# highlight specific divs (tds) onhover of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm just starting to discover how awesome jquery is and how a basic function can drive me nuts to understand. I'm trying to highlight a div with a specific "id" generated via backend

```
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="id_1">
    <h2>id_1 - 
        <a class="marker_id_1" href="#top" name="id_1" id="id_1">Top</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div id="id_1">
    <h2>id_1 - 
        <a class="marker_id_1" href="#top" name="id_1" id="id_1">Bottom</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div id="id_2">
    <h2>id_2 - 
        <a class="marker_id_2" href="#top" name="id_2" id="id_2">Top</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div id="id_2">
    <h2>id_2 - 
        <a class="marker_id_2" href="#top" name="id_2" id="id_2">Bottom</a>
    </h2>
</div>​
```

So if I hover over the "id_1" Top , I want to highlight both the "id_1" Top and Bottom. Below is a link to that so it'll be easier to understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/4PgC6/66/

Thanks!!

Comment: ids within your DOM have to be unique... you will have problems if they aren't

Comment: you can't use same `id` to multiple elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You must not use same `id` for different element.

Using `name`  you can do

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  var name = this.name;
  $('a[name='+ name +']').css('color', '#f00')
},function() {
  var name = this.name;
  $('a[name='+ name +']').css('color', 'blue')
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4PgC6/67/)**

Using `class`

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  var className = this.className;
  $('a.' + className).css('color', '#f00')
},function() {
  var className = this.className;
  $('a.' + className).css('color', 'blue')
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XQwB3/1/)**

if you want to use `.on()` for hover then use

```
$('a').on('hover', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        var divName = this.name;
        console.log(divName);
        $('div', 'td.' + divName).addClass('match-highlight');
    } else {
        var divName = this.name;
        $('div', 'td.' + divName).removeClass('match-highlight');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XQwB3/14/)**

Comment: would you recommend me using name tho? which one would be better? I actually have those divs inside a td. 1 div into 1 td. I want to highlight the whole td if possible, so I guess use classname?

Comment: hey boss, so I'm still ahving some problems. I'm not sure if I'm looking into the "td" correctly. I want the whole cell to change appearance so this is what i did. http://jsfiddle.net/XQwB3/5/

Comment: @gdubs instead of `td[name='+ divName +']` try with `'td.'+ divName`, because your `td` has class same to `a` tag name

Comment: awesome, it worked! but the color isn't going away tho. i guess i have to make another one for hover out? http://jsfiddle.net/XQwB3/10/

Comment: @gdubs second arguments function of `hover()` is for hover out, so set different color in second function of hover.

Comment: ok so on the first try the color of the link changed, went ahead and added a class so that it can just apply that class to the 'td' but it doesnt seem to work. here's the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/XQwB3/12/ this is driving me up the wall.

Comment: perfect! thanks. i wonder why that e.type is needed. maybe version.. btw, do you ever sleep, u reply quick. i appreciate it so much!

Comment: btw, i didn't know how to edit a comment but, do you mind explaining to me as to why there's a "div" before the "td" ?  $('div', 'td.' + divName).addClass('match-highlight');

Comment: Using only `$('td.' + divName)` can't capture the inner elements to you need `$('div', 'td.' + divName)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant have same same ID for a and div. **Id should be unique**. 
Use **data** for that instead. Like that:

```
<a href="#" data-id="id_1"></a>
```

and then read it in script like that:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  divID = $(this).data('id');
  $('#'+divId).css('color', '#f00');
},function() {
  divID = $(this).data('id');
  $('#'+divId).css('color', 'blue');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/4PgC6/69/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
   var hoveredid = $(this).attr('id'); 
    $('[id='+hoveredid+']').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
   var hoveredid = $(this).attr('id'); 
   $('[id='+hoveredid+']').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("highlighted");
    });
});
```

As mentioned, id should be unique. But if it isn't I found accessing using '[id=' rather than '#' you are able to access all divs, since you are looking at id as an attribute.​ (See: http://jsfiddle.net/4PgC6/68/)